# relation of fundamental group for different base point.

Tags: general-topology, fundamental-groups

I want to know the relation between fundamental group based at $x_0$, $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ and fundamental group based at $x_1$, $\pi_1(X,x_1)$, where $X$ is a topological space. and $x_0, x_1 \in X$. What is the relation between them?

Comment: If $x_0$ and $x_1$ are in the same path component, the groups are isomorphic. Have you an idea how an isomorphism between the two might look?

Comment: @Daniel Fischer, How? i don't see the groups are isomorphic if they are in the same path component.

Comment: Join base points by a path, say $\;\alpha\;$, and now "conjugate" by $\;\alpha\;$ loops of one group into the other one's.

Comment: Also, note that if they are not in the same path component, they can be as unrelated as you want them to be (just take the disjoint union of two completely different spaces).